# Get first n rows in a group using SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe as follows:

```
Tags    Place       Count

Sales   New Jersey  200  
Sales   Hong Kong   200  
Sales  Florida     200  
Trade  New York    150  
Trade  San Jose    150  
Trade  New Jersey  150  
Market New Jersey   50  
Market Michigan     50  
Market Denver       50
```

As you can see that the tags are already sorted by "Count" in this table. I want to get first n tags from each group where group is "Tags"

Lets say I get first 2 then the resulting dataframe should be like this:

Tags    Place      Count

```
Sales  New Jersey  200  
Sales  Hong Kong   200  
Trade  New York    150  
Trade  San Jose    150  
Market New Jersey   50  
Market Michigan     50
```

How can I do this in Spark SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is an answer

```
you need to create data frame using HiveContext 

 import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val hivecontext = new HiveContext(sc)
val df= hivecontext.createDataFrame(data,schema)
df.registerTempTable("df")
 hivecontext.sql("SELECT tag,place,count FROM (SELECT tag,place,count,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag) as rank FROM df) tmp WHERE rank <= 2 ORDER BY count DESC").show(false)
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy(df("tag"))
val rankDesc = row_number().over(w).alias("rank")
df.select($"*", rankDesc).filter($"rank" <= 2 || $"rank" <= 2).orderBy($"count".desc).drop($"rank").show(false)
```

output :

```
  +------+----------+-----+
|tag   |place     |count|
+------+----------+-----+
|Sales |Hong Kong |200  |
|Sales |New Jersey|200  |
|Trade |New York  |150  |
|Trade |San Jose  |150  |
|Market|New Jersey|50   |
|Market|Michigan  |50   |
+------+----------+-----+
```